# AngularJS. Passing Service as an argument to Directive

Tags: angularjs

I have my own directive:  `<form-wrapper>`

For now this directive uses its own internal controller that use some `Service` (`User` service)

Like this:

```
 directives.directive("formWrapper", ['User',  function(User) {
        return {
         ...        
         controller: function($scope, $location, User) {

                    $scope.fields = User.get( {id: "1"}  );              // GET
        ...
```

As you can see: I use **hard-coded** Service (`User`).

**Question:** How could I pass Service as an argument to the Directive? To use it like this:

```
  Service = comesFromArgument
  $scope.fields = Service.get( {id: "1"} )
```

I guess if I pass Service name as string (as service name) it will not help. And passing argument usually happens in `link-function` but not in the controller.

**UPDATE (more explanation)** :

When use `directives.directive("formWrapper", ['User',  function(User) {` the name 'User' lead to inject User service, because this it the way how IoC work here I guess. It knows that this is a service. But if I did:

`<form-wrapper service="User">`  **// this is what I want.**

Then, "User" will be just a string, not reference to the User service.

Comment: I don't quite get what you are asking for? What is hard-coded about the Service `User`? This is just a name of the service, what would be the use of this coming from an argument? Do you want to load different Services for different attributes of your directive?

Comment: please, look at my "update" in the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [angular's `$injector` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24injector) to inject a service given a string in your controller.

In the HTML:

```html
<form-wrapper my-attr-with-service="User">
  ...
</form-wrapper>
```

In the directive definition:

```js
controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $injector) {
    var myService = $injector.get($attrs.myAttrWithService);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I'm happy. $injectors.. I expected to get something like this. Thanks :)

Comment: Wath out when min javascript. Above mthod will be broken. Look at @codebased answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use inject using controller.$inject, passing an array.

```
app.module('widgets').directive('formWrapper', formWrapper);

function formWrapper() { 

    return { 
      ... 
     controller: formWrapperController,

 }
}

formWrapperController.$inject = ['dataservice', '$http']

function formWrapperController(dataservice, $http) { }
```

Comment: That is better answer! Minification won't break a thing ;)